# Remove duplicate variable from logic gate

Tags: python, z3, boolean-logic

I want to remove duplicate variable from logic gate. For example, suppose i have the following code:

```
from z3 import *
a = Bool('a')
b = Bool('b')
# c is the same variable as a
c = Bool('a')
or_gate = Or(a, b, c)
```

I want to check whether or_gate contain multiple of the same variable, if yes i want to leave only one and remove the rest.
In above example, i want the or gate to be `Or(a, b)` instead of `Or(a, b, a)`. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you explain your use case further? Why do you need to know if they are the exact same variable?

Comment: @LLL I don't know what that means. Will you please [edit] your question with more detail?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i have edited my question , i hope it isnt confusing anymore

Comment: We do realize that `Bool('b a')` isn't the same as `Bools('b a')` right? `Bool('b a')` doesn't *contain* `b` and `a`, it *is* `'b a'`

Comment: Also `simplify(or_gate)` gives the same as my more complicated work around earlier~

Comment: @BeRT2me thanks your solution worked, do you mind posting it as answer? so i can accept yours because you answered first

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.hash()` method to do that.

```py
if a.hash() == b.hash():
    # they reference the same variable
```

Comment: This worked thank you, upvoted, but i will accept BeRT answer because he answered first.

Comment: @LLL while this might work, it's not guaranteed. `hash` may have collisions. (Extremely rare and you'll unlikely to see it in practice, but possible in theory.) `simplify` would be the way to go. Or, you can write a simple function that inspects the AST and figures out it's the same variable to walk over the arguments. (Of course, that'd be very specific to this one AST node kind.)